# ms-windows-store: how to download from on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, firefox, wine

Ok, I only use Ubuntu, but I love to play windows games, so I'm trying to find a way to install windows games from my browser at the MS store. However, the store always redirects to a "ms-windows-store:/foo/bar/" tab, which is unsupported on firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two options: 1.) `wine`, 2.) Virtual Machine... try those!

Comment: @George Wine doesn't support Modern apps, does it?

Comment: @wjandrea no it doesn't but perhaps OP can find some games there that are also on Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the Microsoft Store site, it is really only a catalog for the real store because is you click download for their software, it will open the store on the Windows computer and download it from there. And in case you are wondering, no, you can not download the Microsoft store from anywhere because it is only available through being pre-installed on Windows 8 and 10 computers. So to summarize it, you can not do anything you asked.